# Method in controller does not exist error - Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have defined the route in web.php

```
Route::name('complaints.')->prefix('complaints')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', [ComplaintController::class, 'index'])
        ->middleware('auth')
        ->name('index');
    
    Route::get('/get-candidates', [ComplaintController::class, 'get-candidates'])
        ->middleware('auth')
        ->name('get-candidates');

});
```

And have created this method in `ComplaintController`

```
public function getCandidates(Request $request){   

    $candidatenames = [];

    echo json_encode($candidatenames);
    
 }
```

But when I try to access this url `http://localhost/complaints/get-candidates` i get this error `Method App\Http\Controllers\ComplaintController::get-candidates does not exist.`

What I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you named your method `getCandidates`, not `get-candidates`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change either
`Route::get('/get-candidates', [ComplaintController::class, 'get-candidates'])` to
`Route::get('/get-candidates', [ComplaintController::class, 'getCandidates'])` or change your function name from getCandidates to get-candidates

Comment: We usually don't answer questions (but vote to close) caused by a typo - they're of no use to other users

Comment: @brombeer actually I was writing my answer till I saw your comment, make sense.

Comment: Provided alternative option is not possible because "A valid function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores." [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).